# I want to create a profile page that retrieve data by using id but i try link the page using button and i got error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use button that link the profile using by using id

```
if($result-> num_rows > 0){ 
    while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "<tr><td>". $row["ic"] ."</td><td>". $row["name"] ."</td><td>". $row["jawatan"] ."</td></tr>";

        echo "<tr><td><button onclick="location.href='testProfile.php?id= $row["ic"]';">quick view</button></td></tr>";

    }
    echo "</table>"; 
 }
```

Comment: Question is unclear.Please elaborate properly.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your problem? And what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to create profile page that retrieve data by using id but i try link the page using button and i got error

Comment: @Rhylex  instead of button create a link and give the url of profile page along with id. now on that page get the id using `$_GET['id']` and then use that id into query to get desired data.You can apply CSS to make your link look like a button

Comment: @Rhylex: what kind of error that you have?

Comment: chaneg button code like this and check:- `echo "<tr><td><button onclick='location.href=testProfile.php?id=".$row['ic']."'>quick view</button></td></tr>";`

Comment: it already shows in the markdown syntax, you need to escape the quotes, plus your code will clearly be open to xss attacks, you're not escaping any of those variables you output

Comment: @AlivetoDie it can run but the link is not working

Answer (score 2):

use anchor tag

```
echo '<tr><td><a href="testProfile.php?id=' . $row["ic"] . '">quick view</a></td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if($result-> num_rows > 0){ 
    while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "<tr><td>". $row["ic"] ."</td><td>". $row["name"] ."</td><td>". $row["jawatan"] ."</td></tr>";

        echo "<tr><td><a href='testProfile.php?id=".$row["ic"]."'>quick view</a></td></tr>";

    }
    echo "</table>"; 
 }
```